The linear independence and linear elimination of non-crossing matching polynomials
Consider the polynomial set:
$$
f_{ij} = (t_i - t_j)x_i x_j + x_i - x_j, \quad (1 \leq j < i \leq 2n)
$$
where $ t_1, t_2, \dots, t_{2n} $ are pairwise distinct.
Let's look at the non-crossing product combinations of these polynomials:
$$
A = \{ f_{i_1 i_2} f_{i_3 i_4} \dots f_{i_{2n-1} i_{2n}} \mid i_1, i_2, \dots, i_{2n} \text{ are pairwise distinct} \}
$$
For example, when  $n = 2 $, we have $$ A = \{ f_{43} f_{21}, f_{42} f_{31}, f_{41} f_{32} \} $$. It can be seen that the number of elements in set $ A $ is # $A = (2n - 1)!! $.
We define the term order of the polynomials as deglex (degree lexicographic). Notice that the degree of each polynomial in $ A $ is $ 2n $, with the leading term $ x_{2n} x_{2n-1} \dots x_2 x_1 $. I found that by taking a linear combination of the polynomials in $ A $, we can obtain a polynomial of degree $ n+1 $:
$$
\exists g(x_{2n}, x_{2n-1}, \dots, x_1), \quad \text{such that } \deg(g) = n + 1 \quad \text{(or } \text{Lt}(g) = x_{2n} x_{2n-1} \dots x_n \text{)}
$$
where
$$
g(x_{2n}, x_{2n-1}, \dots, x_1) = \sum k_{(i_1 i_2)(i_3 i_4) \dots (i_{2n-1} i_{2n})} f_{i_1 i_2} f_{i_3 i_4} \dots f_{i_{2n-1} i_{2n}}
$$
For example, when $ n = 2 $,
$$
g(x_4, x_3, x_2, x_1) = \frac{1}{(t_4 - t_3)(t_2 - t_1)} f_{43} f_{21} - \frac{1}{(t_4 - t_2)(t_3 - t_1)} f_{42} f_{31},
$$
$$
\deg(g) = 3
$$
I also found that the number of linearly independent polynomials in set $ A $ is $ C_n $, where $ C_n $ is the Catalan number, $ C_n = \frac{1}{n+1} \binom{2n}{n} $.
For example, when $ n=2 $, there are 2 linearly independent polynomials: $ f_{43} f_{21} $ and $ f_{42} f_{31} $, but $ f_{41} f_{32} = f_{43} f_{21} - f_{42} f_{31} $.
When $ n=3 $, there are 5 linearly independent polynomials: $ f_{65} f_{43} f_{21}, f_{65} f_{42} f_{31}, f_{64} f_{52} f_{31}, f_{64} f_{53} f_{21}, f_{63} f_{52} f_{41} $.
My questions are:

How can I rigorously prove that it is possible to obtain a polynomial of degree $ n+1 $?
Which theoretical fields does this phenomenon relate to, and are there any relevant research papers on this topic?


What do you mean by noncrossing products? $(2n-1)!!$ is the number of all matchings, the number of noncrossing ones is $C_n$, no?

I have edited it again, and this time the problem description is more accurate
